# Retrieve AD groups of a user in PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to get the group list to which the authenticated user belongs. Http server is Apache2, and I'm binding to an Active Directory server.

As far as I know, the only way I can do it is by getting all the groups that happen to have that user in its `member` attribute.

By doing this:

```
$groups = ldap_list($ldap, 'OU=Groups,DC=server,DC=com', '(objectClass=group)', ['cn']);
```

It works perfectly well, I get all the group names in `$groups`. So far so good.

Now, after making sure the authenticated user (say ***userdp08***) is in the ***member*** attribute of several of the groups formerly listed, i change the filter:

```
$groups = ldap_list($ldap, 'OU=Groups,DC=server,DC=com',
    '(&(member=userdp08)(objectClass=group))', ['cn']);
```

Well, now I don't get any group. In case ***member*** attribute uses the full ***DN*** of the users, I change to:

```
$groups = ldap_list($ldap, 'OU=Groups,DC=server,DC=com',
    '(&(member=CN=userdp08*)(objectClass=group))', ['cn']);
```

I've tried all these filters, to no avail:

```
'(&(member=*CN=userdp08*)(objectClass=group))'
'(&(member=*userdp08*)(objectClass=group))'
'(&(member=*08*)(objectClass=group))'
```

And even this one doesn't work:

```
'(objectClass=gro*)'
```

However, if I retrieve the full ***DN*** of the user and I use it in an exact match filter, I get the appropriate groups correctly.

My question is: as it seems that **substring filters** are not working, is it possible that they are disabled in the *AD* configuration? I mean, can they be disabled somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding substring filters, your question is about [which/how attributes are indexed in AD](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-active-directory-identity/indexing-in-active-directory/ba-p/243119).

There is no substring index for the `member` attribute (actually by default it is not indexed), so you *must* pass the full dn to get a match, or modify the [**searchFlags**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms808539(v=msdn.10)#the-searchflags-property) property to specify the index for the attribute in the schema.

It is also good to know that `objectCategory` is indexed, while `objectClass` is not.

But this is not the only way to retrieve user's groups. In AD you got the `memberOf` attribute which makes membership filtering easier and more performant (in OpenLDAP this is not enabled by default). As its name implies, you can query for a given user and read the `memberOf` attribute to get all groups that user is a member of, eg. :

```
$groups = ldap_list($ldap, 'OU=Users,DC=server,DC=com', 
        '(&(objectCategory=person)(CN=userdp08*))', ['memberOf']);
```

or :

```
$groups = ldap_list($ldap, 'OU=Users,DC=server,DC=com', 
        '(sAMAccountName=userdp08)', ['memberOf']);
```

The drawback is that you only get the value(s) for that attribute, which is/are the dn's of such groups, so if you want to read their `cn`, you still have to lookup for the matching group entries.

@see [Indexed attributes in AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/attributes-indexed)